# Http Session is not expiring

Tags: java, session

I am using spring security in my application and I have added the below code in my AuthenticationFilter.

```
request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60 * 60);
```

I have remote debugged the code and made sure that this code is executed on successful authentication. The problem I am facing is my session doesn't expire after 1 minute. When I inspected the session object , I could see that there is a flag expiring=false. I am not sure what this flag all about.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: have you place your session-timeout xml element within a session-config xml element?

Comment: your web.xml seems okay to me. You have it in the right place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setMaxInactiveInterval` is specified in seconds. So set to 60.

from the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29):

> setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval) 
>             Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session.

### About the expiring flag

`expiring` is not part of the HttpSession interface. I am guessing you are using Tomcat, which has a StandardSession base class which has such a [property](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.html). According to the docs it is a protected field and used for testing purposes only.

> protected boolean expiring
>   We are currently processing a session expiration, so bypass certain IllegalStateException tests.

It is normal that this property is set to false most of the time.

Comment: :) . That was a bit naive from my side after doing all the hardwork :P..Could you please explain me why the session-timeout doesnt work with spring security. and what the expiring flag means.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your session-timeout element I can only assume that it is either in the wrong place in your web.xml or you have not placed it in the right web.xml. Your application container should pick it up regardless of spring security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detaioled explanation. I have updated my question with the web.xml. Could you please check if there is a problem with my config